# Get substring from a string when substring is defined in a vector

Tags: r

Lets say I have a vector like so

```
foo <- c('est','bel','cat')
```

and then I have a string like so:

```
str <- "test"
```

How can I get "est" to be returned

Comment: It seems like you want fuzzy string matching. If you include "fuzzy" in searches for solutions (here and Google) you'll likely find something useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
foo[str_detect(str, foo)]
#> [1] "est"
```

And when multiple valid substrings appear:

```
foo <- c('est','bel','cat', 'tes')
foo[str_detect(str, foo)]
#> [1] "est" "tes"
```

Comment: Didn't know that function from `stringr`. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

`which(sapply(foo, (function(x) grepl(x, str)))==T)`

Comment: Or just `which(sapply(foo, grepl, str))`

Comment: `which` returns indices, not values. Can replace as `foo[sapply(foo, grepl, str)]`